# meaning of "all-before" and "all-after" in makefiles

Tags: makefile

```
    .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

    all: all-before ../Flock.exe all-after
```

Since it's in .PHONY, it must be a Makefile keyword, but I don't know what it means or even does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not keywords, they are referring to rules that are named `all-before` and `all-after` such that the former is invoked before building the executable and the latter is invoked right after. They are mentioned in the .PHONY because these are not filenames.

Bad example:

```
all: all-before binary all-after

binary:
  gcc input.c -o binary

all-before:
  -mkdir bin

all-after:
  -cp binary bin
```

Comment: ignore it if it is not doing something useful in the makefile you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a makefile keyword. It's probably the name of another target defined somewhere else in the makefile (but I can't be sure without more context of the file).

Answer (score 0):

They are just pre-inserted targets to get customization done. 
See the code added to makefile and use that modified makefile.win

### Processing makefile...

- Makefile Processor: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\bin\mingw32-make.exe
- Command: mingw32-make.exe -f "MakefileMy.win" 
  ----> added lines below
  .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all-before:
    @echo " all before"

all-after:
    @echo  "all after done"

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

--> partial compile.log  file from DevC on Windows 10 machine:

all
" all before"
 "all after done"

### Compilation results...

- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0